# Collapsing a Table header in a DataTable is breaking my table format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use a data table that has a header, sub header and 3 rows.

There are 4 sub headers named Event 1..4
Next to each sub header are 3 rows of data

When I click on the sub header, the sub header is collapsing, but the rows from sub header 2 are leaking over

You can see it happening in Fiddler below, Click on the Event1 , then Event2 and you will see the format of the DataTable break.

I would like to see each event collapse into Event with the 3 rows showing scores.

How can I collapse the sub headers and keep the formatting correct.

```
$('.header').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100).promise().done(function () {
        $this.find('span').text(function (_, value) {
            return value == '-' ? '+' : '-'
        });
    });
});
```

Fiddler project below

http://jsfiddle.net/nc8bt9ss/873/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cells in the three sub-rows can be toggled with the following function:

```
$('th').click(function () {
   $(this).parent().next('tr').addBack().next('tr').addBack().children('td').slideToggle(200).promise();
});
```

This changes the mouse cursor to pointer (hand) for the first sub-row for some reason, although the click function only runs on the header.  To address that issue, use CSS to set the mouse cursor on all TD elements to default:

```
td {
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: One question, why does the whole top row become clickable and not just Event 1?

Comment: Because the `$('.header')` selector selects the entire row.  I'll see if I can rework it.

Comment: How can I have only the Event I click in focus and hides the others.
If I click on Event 3, all others are collapsed..

Comment: I would recommend that you post another question for that as it isn't something that I can easily answer in a comment.  If I were doing it, I would use the code that is generating the table to add a class to each cell such as "event1", "event2", then you could easily select all cells that are not associated with a particular event.